# Story of Bayta Darell and The Mule in Asimov's Foundation Series

Tags: isaac-asimov, foundation

To my knowledge, I have "read" all of the Foundation books, however I "read" (heard) them in audiobook format, out of sequence, and over the course of 5 years. I am re-reading *Second Foundation* and am very confused.

[image: Second Foundation]

The book started off with the story of General Hans Pritcher, [Bail Channis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bail_Channis), [The Mule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mule_(Foundation)), and the First Speaker. That story ended with the First Speaker wiping knowledge of the Second Foundation from The Mule's mind.

What I thought I would then hear a story I remember wherein The Mule was finally killed by Bayta Darell. Instead, I started hearing the story of Bayta's granddaughter Arkady Darell.

What I'm wondering is if there was some technical error with my audiobook (I skipped over the story of Bayta Darell?) or if that was a part of another book and, if so, which book that was.

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The development in the books is:

- At the end of "The Mule", the first Mule story (second part of the "Foundation & Empire" book) Bayta Darrell (the heroine) kills Ebling Mis to avoid him informing the Mule of the Second Foundation location.
- Then appears the story of the Mule search of the Second Foundation, "Search By the Mule" (first part of the "Second Foundation" book), and his defeat at the hands of the Second Foundation First Speaker (they don't kill him, they just "realign" him).
- And then the Arkady Darrell story, "Search by the Foundation" (second part of "Second Foundation") where the Mule is no more, the First Foundation is independent again and also searching for the Second Foundation.

So your audiobook appears to be correct.

Comment: Oh, ok. So if I read this correctly, the stories were kind of told out of chronological order. So the story I was thinking of was at the end of "Foundation & Empire" and then "Second Foundation" starts before the aforementioned story and continues after the aforementioned story. Got it.

Comment: The stories are in chronological order, as described in this answer.  I'm not sure what's making you think they're not?  (Note that the Mule dies of natural causes between "Search By the Mule" and "Search by the Foundation".)